# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when I try to parse Json on spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jackson

I've got an issues when i'm trying to use com.typesafe.play play-json 2.4.0
on spark.
The follwing code make an exception on the spark server but it works perfectly on my pc.

```
val json = Json.parse(json_string)
```

the exeption :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken.id()I
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:122)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:108)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(JacksonJson.scala:103)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2860)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1569)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JacksonJson.scala:226)
    at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:21)
    at org.soprism.kafka.connector.TwitterToCassandraPostsParser$.ParseJson(TwitterToCassandraPostsParser.scala:74)
    at org.soprism.kafka.connector.TwitterToCassandraPostsParser$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TwitterToCassandraPostsParser.scala:65)
    at org.soprism.kafka.connector.TwitterToCassandraPostsParser$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TwitterToCassandraPostsParser.scala:65)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:798)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:798)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1503)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I use a spark-submit command to execute it

It seems to be an incompatibily between two versions of jackson's library. How can I fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have _jackson-core_ set up as a dependency?

Comment: Yes I have this one : "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.5.4"

Answer (score 1):

Spark nodes will NOT check your dependencies. You need to build an uber-jar that includes all your dependencies and pass it to Spark in order to be distributed to the different node.

Comment: I've put jackson on the jar but it does't work on spark. Spark takes always a old version of jackson. This old version is on hadoop i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie has a lot of outdated jackson libs in shared lib fodler:

```
[cloudera@quickstart oozie]$ sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -ls -R /user/oozie/share | grep -i jackson-core
-rwxrwxrwx   1 oozie supergroup     191738 2015-11-18 03:00 /user/oozie/share/lib/hive/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     191738 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/hcatalog/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     227500 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/hcatalog/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     191738 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/hive/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     227500 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/hive/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     227500 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/hive2/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     227500 2015-11-18 03:01 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/pig/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     192699 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/spark/jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     227500 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/spark/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 oozie supergroup     197986 2015-11-18 03:02 /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_20151118030154/sqoop/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 oozie supergroup     227500 2015-11-18 03:00 /user/oozie/share/lib/pig/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 oozie supergroup     195678 2015-11-18 03:00 /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
-rwxrwxrwx   1 oozie supergroup     224637 2015-11-18 03:00 /user/oozie/share/lib/sqoop/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
[cloudera@quickstart oozie]$
```

Use following props in  section in workflow.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.launcher.mapreduce.task.classpath.user.precedence</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

Here's a bug in Oozie. Check out following links for details:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OOZIE-2066
http://gbif.blogspot.com.by/2014/11/upgrading-our-cluster-from-cdh4-to-cdh5.html

Don't forget to add jackson in uber jar for Oozie lib.