# Parsing JSON with a Hive UDF in Scala

Tags: scala, hive, udf, play-json

I'm trying to write a Scala UDF for Hive which acts on a JSON array -- extending `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF` and and relying on play-json's `play.api.libs.json.parse`.

When attempting to call this from within Hive, I see `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken.id()I`.

I'm not sure what the cause is here--some incompatibility with the jackson versions, and if so, how can I work around this?

The only component/version that I'm tied to is Hive 1.2.

Comment: Is your JSON dependency correct one? Is your UDF jar contains the JSON dependency with correct version?

Comment: The UDF is packaged (with sbt-assembly) with its dependencies (with the exception of Hadoop/Hive where I am using the ones provided). As a stand-alone function it tests/works fine.

Comment: whats the version of jackson core jar in the UDF fat jar?

Comment: I've tried a few...what should I be aiming for? The play-json version mainly dictates my options in that regard.

Comment: The problem could be your cluster is taking the old version of jackson jar which is causing issue or there are two different jars contain the same class name [JsonToken] , check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142340/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-when-i-try-to-parse-json-on-spark

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the JSON UDF's in Brickhouse ( http://github.com/klout/brickhouse ).  Brickhouse has UDF's `to_json` and `from_json` , as well as a convenience functions `json_map` and `json_split` to deal directly with maps and arrays.

In regards to your versioning problem, Brickhouse uses jackson under the covers, using version 1.8.8 (among others), and I haven't come across this particular versioning problem.

Answer (score 0):

The guess that this is a Jackson incompatibility makes sense.

Hive 1.2 uses [Jackson 1.9.2](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-1.2/pom.xml#L131) but later versions are used by recent versions (i.e. last couple of years) of Play-JSON.

If reverting to an old enough version of Play-JSON doesn't make sense, then perhaps the simplest workaround would be to use a Scala JSON parsing library that doesn't depend on Jackson; [Rapture JSON](https://github.com/propensive/rapture/blob/dev/doc/json.md) can be used with multiple backends and so might be a good choice.